# Aws ecr LayersNotFoundException but layers actually present in registry

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I am trying to retag and copy an image from a repository to another within the same repository, without the use of Docker but only with the aws cli
I first get the manifest for the image i want to copy (step 1), i get this without any exception, but when i try to `put` it to the new repository (step 2), aws tells me the layers are not there, i find it strange because if i get the layers from the manifest in step 1 it means that they are there, those are the commands i am running:
Step 1:

```
MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name REPO_NAME --image-ids imageTag=THE_CURRENT_IMMAGE_TAG --profile MY_PROFILE --output json | jq --raw-output '.images[].imageManifest')
```

Step 2:

```
aws ecr put-image --repository-name NEW_REPOSITORY_NAME --image-tag NEW_IMAGE_TAG --image-manifest "$MANIFEST" --profile MY_PROFILE
```

This returns:

```
An error occurred (LayersNotFoundException) when calling the PutImage operation: Layers with digests '[sha256....]'required for pushing image into repository with name 'NEW_REPOSITORY_NAME ' in the registry with id 'MY_REGISTRY' do not exist
```

I cant figure out what am i doing wrong here, unfortunately i cant find any examples online similar to mine, any idea?